# What kind of image do I use for my Default.png? I'm using the iPhone 5's native resolution WITH the status bar, but it won't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Is this a bug? My Default-568h@2x.png image is 640x1136 (*with* the status bar), yet when I open it (either from a run in the simulator, or a cold launch from my phone) the old status bar creeps through. I thought this was supposed to be cut out and replaced with the user's?

Here's an image (apologies for the size):

[image]

What do I do? To the best of my knowledge it only happens on iPhone 5 resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with portrait or landscape.

I figured out the obvious thing - your status bar style is black translucent. You should either change it to black opaque OR black out the statusbar on your Default image to make things work.

Comment: Black opaque worked. I still find it odd it only occurred with iPhone 5s.

Comment: Gratz! Can you please set this as an answer?